# Checking for content using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm using fetch to make API calls which return JSON data.

Sometimes the API call returns a status `OK` and `null` for content. I was relying on checking the status to get the content but this gives me an error because there's no JSON data.

The error I'm getting is: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Here's my typical fetch pattern and clearly I need to improve it by adding one more check for JSON data. How should I modify this?

```
export const getSomeData = () => {

    return (dispatch) => fetch('/api/myapifunction', fetchOptionsGet())
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.ok) {
                // I need to add logic here to check for JSON data before calling parseJSON
                parseJSON(response)
                .then(data => {
                    // Do something
                })
            } else {
                // Failed
                // Handle failure
            }
        })
}
```

I created functions for fetchOptions such as GET or POST as well as parseJSON. They're simple functions. This is what parseJSON looks like:

```
export const parseJSON = (response) => {
    return response.json();
}
```

As I understand it, response.json() is simply a promise, not necessarily data. How do I check to see if I'm getting any JSON data?

Comment: Try `if(response && response.ok)`.

Comment: Why do you need to check for JSON data *before* calling response.json()? Because that should return a promise for a value of `null` if your API call truly returns that. You have a `then` after `parseJSON(response)` so just check the `data` argument to see if there's anything there, like `if (data) {`...

Comment: That didn't work because there is a response.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan looks like I'm not even getting into .then. Looks like the error is thrown right before the .then

Comment: Your question never mentions an error... Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include that?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry! I updated the original post too but the error is: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Ah, okay, so it's not passing "null", it's passing nothing; zero bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response.json()` promise will run correctly and get into the `.then` part if the browser was able to parse the content of the response as a valid json.

In case it wasn't able to do so - you can use the `.catch` to see what the problem was:

```
parseJSON(response)
    .then(json => {
        // Do something with the json data
    }).catch( reason => {
        // response is not a valid json string
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is that your service is being a bit duplicitous. It's saying it's `OK`, but then sending no bytes at all. `JSON.parse('')` throws that same error.

You can solve this by using the `catch` as Dekel notes, or you can use `response.text()`:

```
if (response.ok) {
  response.text()
    .then(text => text && text.length ? response.json() : Promise.resolve({}))
    .then(data => { // here you'll need to handle an empty object
```

That basically checks the string value of what's returned. If there's nothing being returned, it will give you an empty object instead of throwing an error. That will help differentiate between a JSON parse error because of bad data, and no data at all.

Comment: Thank you. The catch block fixes the error. Interestingly though, even if the API returns 204 i.e. no content, I was still getting an error. This post (https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/268) was talking about the same error and the last suggestion is to return a 204 but like I said, that doesn't really help either. The catch block is a good solution. I think it may be a better idea to modify my parseJSON to encapsulate all the checks in there.

Comment: On second thought, encapsulating all this in parseJSON may be a bad idea.